# Bootstrap Flex Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have built my website and am now trying to make it responsive. My question relates to a page on my website which is made up of 8 full viewport height containers. These containers are split into two equal columns (aligned side by side horizontally) using Bootstrap 4. For any devices smaller than an iPad/tablet I would like to be able to align these two columns below one another vertically. Is this possible? If so how do I achieve this. The key point is that I only want the columns to be aligned this way for small devices.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You haven't provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are not getting collapsible columns.

Your columns not collapsing at certain screen widths could be due to a variety of reasons:

1. Bootstrap is not linked properly. I have given an example of Bootstrap 4.1.3 minified version in the code snippet below.
2. Bootstrap is outdated and you are using an old version that does not match your existing code.
3. A common mistake is not having your `col` wrapped in a `<div class="row">`.
4. You have not specified the collapse state of the column which can be either col-[sm/md/lg/xl]-

Bootstrap columns should automatically stack at `768px` width when using `col-md`. This changes for each collapsible state.

If you would like to read more about Bootstraps grid system you can [click here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

As an example here is a code snippet you can use for future reference:

```css
.container .row .col-md-4 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!-- BOOTSTRAP CDN LINK -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Make col-4, col-[sm/md/lg/xl]-4 for different screen widths -->
    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Column 1<p></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Column 2<p></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><p>Column 3<p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***NOTE:**
To see this code snippet working, expand it to full-screen and/or change the width of the code snippet until a collapse occurs.